# Thread safety for class instance access

Tags: c++, multithreading, thread-safety, thread-synchronization

In my application, I have the following Worker class (sample/example code):

The `instance_` is accessed by `WorkerThread`'s member thread to start/stop timer and read the file names.

```
class WorkerThread {

   std::thread                                    thread_;
   boost::asio::io_service                        ios_;
   boost::optional<boost::asio::io_service::work> work_;
   std::vector<std::string>                       file_names_vec_;

   static thread_local WorkerThread*             instance_;

   // Some member functions
   void startTimer();
   void stopTimer();
  
   void pushFileNames(std::string filename) {
      file_names_vec_.push_back(filename);
   }


};
```

And another class as `WorkerManager` class. Only accessed by the main-thread.

```
class WorkerManager {

   std::vector<WorkerThread *> WorkerThreadVec_;

   // Some member functions
   void pushFileToThreads(std::string filename) {
      for (auto& worker : WorkerThreadVec_) {
         worker->pushFileNames(filename);
      }
   }

};
```

The main-thread creates the worker threads by instantiating the `WorkerThread` class and saves the instance pointers in its vector.

The instance of `WorkerManager` class gets accessed by the main-thread to add/remove filenames from the `WorkerThread` instance's data structures. These filenames get read by the member `thread_` of `WorkerThread` using the `WorkerThread* instance_`.

The member `thread_` of `WorkerThread` also accesses the `WorkerThread* instance_` at every 2 seconds to start and stop the timer.

Based on the above design, I have following questions:

1. Is the thread-safety compromised in above design? Do I need to protect the access to `WorkerThread* instance_` to ensure mutual exclusion between the main-thread and the member `thread_` of `WorkerThread` class? The application has not reported any issue in this code flow as of now though.
2. If I need to protect the access to `WorkerThread* instance_`, then what should be the best approach considering performance?
   The member `thread_` of `WorkerThread` would be accessing the `WorkerThread* instance_` as fast as every 100 milliseconds. Whereas the main-thread would be accessing it once in 2-3 minutes. I'm just thinking whether a mutex would be costly for the member `thread_` of `WorkerThread`.

Comment: As long as noone is writing the `instance_`, you won't have problems with thread safety for the variable itself. But I expect that you will have a problem with `file_names_vec_` since I assume that the main thread will add items while the worker threads will remove them (potentially at the same time). For more details, you need to show all relevant accesses to your variables. For example, where is `instance_` set?

Comment: yeah, and even if the worker threads don't remove anything, it could still be a problem in a case where  the main thread is pushing a new file to the vector and at the same time worker thread is doing a filename look-up in the same vector. Not sure how safe that is to do.

Comment: Not safe at all. Thread A is reading data. Main thread adds an item. `vector` resizes and deletes the data Thread A was reading and replaces it. Wham! And not the good ol' 80's kind of Wham!

Comment: Some potentially useful viewing: [CppCon 2014: Herb Sutter "Lock-Free Programming (or, Juggling Razor Blades)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c1gO9aB9nbs)

Comment: You need to synchronize access. The simplest solution is `std::mutex`.